# FingerPrint SDK experience

Tags: java, c++, c, fingerprint

Anyone knows a free and good SDK for fingerprint? I did a lot of searched but found very little result, so if anyone knows a good SDK or experience in fingerprint I am interested

Comment: http://www.neurotechnology.com/free-fingerprint-verification-sdk.html

Comment: @vishal,  Neurotechnology is under license, it's not free !

Answer (score 2):

The [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/) provide a free SDK for fingerprint:

http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm

- There's a a minutiae detector : MINDTC (to extract template from image)
- And a fingerprint matching algorithm, BOZORTH3

Comment: This sdk interested me, did you have any experience with this SDK?

Comment: Are you french? If you are can we discuss about this?  @LaurentY

Comment: Yes I'm French. We could discuss

Comment: put skype id in your profil description

Comment: not sorry I made a mistake in my Skype nickname, is corrected now @LaurentY